# Arduino LCD only display image for few second and turn screen to white

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, lcd, arduino-due, c

I have a problem with my Arduino and LCD touch screen. I create a few functional button in my Arduino. One of the button is START button. Right now, I want the image is display when I touch START button but the problem is when i touch the START button, the image is display only few second and turn to white screen. How can I solve this problem. Need someone help regarding on this simple issue. Here I attach my code.

**page_testing_v2.ino**

```
#include <Elegoo_GFX.h>                   // Core graphics library
#include <Elegoo_TFTLCD.h>                // Hardware-specific library
#include <TouchScreen.h>                  // Touch Support

#define TS_MINX 903
#define TS_MINY 914
#define TS_MAXX 90
#define TS_MAXY 108
#define YP A3                             // must be an analog pin, use "An" notation!
#define XM A2                             // must be an analog pin, use "An" notation!
#define YM 9                              // can be a digital pin
#define XP 8                              // can be a digital pin

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);

// macros for color (16 bit)
#define BLACK   0x0000
#define BLUE    0x001F
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF
#define GREY    0xD6BA
#define TURQUOISE 0x448E
#define GREENEON  0x67E9
#define PURPLE    0x7018
#define LILAC     0xAC38

#define LCD_CS A3                         // Chip Select goes to Analog 3
#define LCD_CD A2                         // Command/Data goes to Analog 2
#define LCD_WR A1                         // LCD Write goes to Analog 1
#define LCD_RD A0                         // LCD Read goes to Analog 0
#define LCD_RESET A4                      // Can alternately just connect to Arduino's reset pin

Elegoo_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

#define MINPRESSURE 10
#define MAXPRESSURE 1000

extern uint8_t tankIcon[];

boolean button1 = true;
int touch = 0;

char currentPage, selectedUnit;

const int led1 = 51;
const int led2 = 53;

int led1State = LOW;
int led2State = LOW;

unsigned long previous = 0;

unsigned long current = 0;
long elapsed = current - previous;

long cycle = 10000;

//Start the system sequence
void startSystem(){
  current = millis();
  elapsed = current - previous;

  if (elapsed >= cycle){  // this if statement resets the cycle timer
    previous = current;
    //previous = previous + cycle;
  }    
  if (elapsed > 500 && elapsed < 5000){
    led1State = LOW;
    led2State = HIGH;
  }
  if (elapsed > 5500 && elapsed < 10000){
    led2State = LOW;
    led1State = HIGH;
  }
//
//  else
//  {
//    led2State = HIGH;
//    led1State = HIGH;
//  }
  
    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(led1, led1State);
    digitalWrite(led2, led2State);
}
    
void stopSystem(){
  current = millis();
  elapsed = current - previous;

  if(elapsed >= cycle)  // this if statement resets the cycle timer
    //previous = current;
    previous = previous + cycle;
        
    if (elapsed > 1000 && elapsed < 19999){
      led1State = LOW;
      led2State = LOW;
    }

    
    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(led1, led1State);
    digitalWrite(led2, led2State);

    return millis() - current;
}

void drawHomeScreen(){
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);                  // Black Background
  //Draw white frame
  tft.drawRect(0,0,319,240,WHITE);  
   //Title at home screen
  tft.setCursor(25,5);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("Compressed Air System");
   //Draw line under title
  tft.drawLine(0,30,320,30,WHITE);
  //Add text with frame 'SYSTEM'
  tft.setCursor(10,35);
  tft.setTextColor(YELLOW);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("SYSTEM");
   //Add START button
  tft.fillRect(95,38,105,70,GREEN);
  tft.drawRect(95,38,105,70,WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(115,55);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("START");
   //Add PAUSE button
   //Add RESUME button
   //Add E-STOP button (to shut down the whole system if anything happens)
  tft.fillRect(205,38,105,70,RED);
  tft.drawRect(205,38,105,70,WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(230,55);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("STOP");
    //Draw line 
  tft.drawLine(0,115,320,115,WHITE);
   //Add text with frame 'MANUAL'
  tft.setCursor(10,120);
  tft.setTextColor(YELLOW);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("MANUAL");  
   //Add text with frame 'COMPRESSOR 1'
  tft.setCursor(40,140);
  tft.setTextColor(MAGENTA);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Compressor 1"); 
   //Add ON/OFF button
  tft.fillRect(0,150,80,75,GREEN);
  tft.drawRect(0,150,80,75,WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(25,180);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("ON");   

  tft.fillRect(80,150,80,75,RED);
  tft.drawRect(80,150,80,75,WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(100,180);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("OFF");
  
    //Draw line 
  tft.drawLine(160,115,160,240,WHITE);
  
   //Add text with frame 'COMPRESSOR 2'
  tft.setCursor(200,140);
  tft.setTextColor(MAGENTA);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Compressor 2");
  
   //Add ON/OFF button
  tft.fillRect(160,150,80,75,GREEN);
  tft.drawRect(160,150,80,75,WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(185,180);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("ON");   

  tft.fillRect(240,150,80,75,RED);
  tft.drawRect(240,150,80,75,WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(260,180);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("OFF");

}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  tft.reset();                            // Reset LCD
  tft.begin(0x9341);                      // Initialise LCD
  tft.setRotation(3);

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);

  drawHomeScreen();

}

void loop() {
    TSPoint p = ts.getPoint(); 
    if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) {
      p.x = map(p.x, TS_MAXX, TS_MINX, 0, 240);
      p.y = map(p.y, TS_MAXY, TS_MINY, 0, 320);
      pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
      Serial.print("("); Serial.print(p.x);
      Serial.print(", "); Serial.print(p.y);
      Serial.println(")");
//    if (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE) {
//      p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, tft.width(), 0);
//      p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, tft.height(), 0); 
 
    //start button
    if (p.x > 38 && p.x < 108){
      if(p.y > 95 && p.y < 200) {
        touch = 1; 
        }
     }
     
    //stop button
    if (p.x > 38 && p.x < 108){
      if(p.y > 205 && p.y < 310){
        touch = 2;
        }
      }

    //C1 ON button  
    if (p.x > 150 && p.x < 225){
      if(p.y > 0 && p.y < 80){
        touch = 3;
        }
      }

    //C1 OFF button  
    if (p.x > 150 && p.x < 225){
      if(p.y > 80 && p.y < 160){
        touch = 4;
        }
      }
      
    //C2 ON button  
    if (p.x > 150 && p.x < 225){
      if(p.y > 160 && p.y < 240){
        touch = 5;
        }
      }
      
    //C2 OFF button  
    if (p.x > 150 && p.x < 225){
      if(p.y > 240 && p.y < 320){
        touch = 6;
        }
      }

    //home button
    if (p.x > 10 && p.x < 40){
      if(p.y > 10 && p.y < 40){
        touch = 7;
        }
      }            
  }
  if (touch == 1){
    tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
    tft.drawBitmap(200, 45, tankIcon, 120, 116,GREEN);
    tft.fillRect(10,10,30,30,GREEN);
    tft.drawRect(10,10,30,30,RED);
    tft.setCursor(120,160);
    tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.print("Button 1");
    startSystem();
    //touch = 0;

    //return millis() - screen;
    }
    
  if (touch == 2){
//    tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
//    tft.setCursor(120,160);
//    tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
//    tft.setTextSize(2);
//    tft.print("Button 2");
//    touch = 0;
    stopSystem();
    }
    
  if (touch == 3){
//    tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
//    tft.setCursor(120,160);
//    tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
//    tft.setTextSize(2);
//    tft.print("Button 3");
//    touch = 0;
    digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
    //touch = 0;
   
    }
    
  if (touch == 4){
//    tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
//    tft.setCursor(120,160);
//    tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
//    tft.setTextSize(2);
//    tft.print("Button 4");
//    touch = 0;
    digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
    touch = 0;
    
    }
    
  if (touch == 5){
//    tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
//    tft.setCursor(120,160);
//    tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
//    tft.setTextSize(2);
//    tft.print("Button 5");
//    touch = 0;
    digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    touch = 0;
    }
    
  if (touch == 6){
//    tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
//    tft.setCursor(120,160);
//    tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
//    tft.setTextSize(2);
//    tft.print("Button 6");
//    touch = 0;
    digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
    touch = 0;
    }
  if (touch == 7){ 
    drawHomeScreen();
    touch = 0;
  }  
}

void drawBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y,const uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t w, int16_t h, uint16_t color) {
  int16_t i, j, byteWidth = (w + 7) / 8;
  uint8_t byte;
  for(j=0; j<h; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<w; i++) {
      if(i & 7) byte <<= 1;
      else      byte   = pgm_read_byte(bitmap + j * byteWidth + i / 8);
      if(byte & 0x80) tft.drawPixel(x+i, y+j, color);
    }
  }
}
  
  /*TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
  boolean led_state = false;
  if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000)             // Check touch validity
  {
    p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, tft.width(), 0);
    p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, tft.height(), 0);
    if (p.x > 0 && p.x < 240)
    {
      if (p.y > 0 && p.y < 160)
      {
        led_state = true;                 // Touched in Green rectangle
      } 
      else if (p.y > 160 && p.y < 320)
      {
        led_state = false;                // Touched in RED rectangle
      } 
    }
    Serial.print("LED State ");
    Serial.println(led_state);            // Print the status of the LED
  }
  delay (100);*/
```

**systemImages.c**

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

```
// 'tankIcon', 120x116px
const unsigned char tankIcon [] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xf8, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xfe, 0xf1, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xe1, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x03, 0xf8, 0xfb, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0xff, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 
    0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc0, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xff, 0xff, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x01, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x01, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
    0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

Comment: Your question is probably more related to processing button presses and the LCD drawing code is presents an obstacle to someone here trying to help you.  If you're able to ask the same question with code that *compiles, runs, demonstrates the same problem*, but *without* the LCD drawing code, you're more likely to get useful responses.

Comment: The question is tagged with all three of arduino-uno, arduino-mega, and arduino-due.  Why is that?